# Chrome no longer playing video files locally

Tags: google-chrome, mp4, chromecast

I've always used Chrome on my chromebook to play my video files so that I can cast them to my TV using Chromecast, recently however none of my videos will play in the chrome web browser, when I try clicking and dragging the file into chrome the arrow/hand has a red circle around it and won't play the file. The files I am trying are .mp4's which have previously always worked, any suggestion why it won't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You should file a bug against Chrome. This is not a coding question.